# Is there a more efficient way to insert a new array variable based on the content already in the array

Tags: php, arrays

Essentially as per the title. The following code works nicely but seems like a rather long winded process to do what seems to be a rather simple task.

I am going to have a look at how foreach works as an alternative to this but I was wondering If have actually approached this problem correctly.

EDIT: For instance I have seen people use "{}" to concatenate rather than "." saying that it is faster, but I have been unable to get them to work in this piece of code.

```
<?php
// Create Array
    $foobar = array(
        "foo" => "test1",
        "bar" => "hello",
        "far" => "this",
        "boo" => "is",
    //  "foo_result" => "", // Uncomment to check that function does nothing where foo_result already available
    "foo_link" => "http://1.media.collegehumor.cvcdn.com/82/16/162e153d618d49869783ccd475005fd5.jpg",
    "for" => "cool"
);

function _insertarray($foobar) {
// provide arrays to test against
    $foo1 = array("test1","test2");
    $foo2 = array("test3","test4");
    $foo3 = array("test5","test6");
    $foo4 = array("test7","test8");

// End function where "foo_result" is already set
    if (isset($foobar['foo_result'])) {
        // Nothing to do
    }
    else { 

    // add the variable to the foo_result index based on values returned
        if ((count(array_intersect($foo1, $foobar))) ? true : false) {
            $foobar['foo_result'] = "<iframe src='" . $foobar["foo_link"] . "'>";
        }
        else if ((count(array_intersect($foo2, $foobar))) ? true : false) {
            $foobar['foo_result'] = "<a href='" . $foobar["foo_link"] . "'>";
        }
        else if ((count(array_intersect($foo3, $foobar))) ? true : false) {
            $foobar['foo_result'] = "<img src='" . $foobar["foo_link"] . "'>";
        }
        else if ((count(array_intersect($foo4, $foobar))) ? true : false) {
            $foobar['foo_result'] = "<iframe src='" . $foobar["foo_link"] . "'>";
        }
        else {
            // Nothing to do here
        }
    }
    return $foobar;     
}
    print_r(_insertarray($foobar));
?>
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Just to clarify, do you mean efficient as in 'less CPU time' or efficient as in 'shorter/nicer code'

Comment: Why do you write `if (blah ? true : false)` instead of just `if (blah)`?

Comment: @Patashu I mean Less CPU time, and if it results in shorter code its a bonus.

Comment: @Barmar I thought it was good practice to write it that way, I have been teaching myself from the Php manual hence the reason why I am not sure if the approach I have taken is a good approach or if it could be done to run faster and more efficiently.

Comment: You don't even need to call `count()`, an empty array is treated as `false` by `if`.

Comment: I doubt that string interpolation is noticeably faster than using `.`. I like interpolation just because it makes the code easier to read.

Comment: That is good to know. Thanks for the help. @Barmar has given a solution that I am going to work on understanding.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think this will be much faster in CPU time, but it simplifies the code by removing all the repetition.

```
$test_array = array(
  array('check' => array("test1", "test2"),
        'format' => '<iframe src="%s">'),
  array('check' => array("test3", "test4"),
        'format' => '<a href="%s">'),
  array('check' => array("test5", "test6"),
        'format' => '<img src="%s">'),
  array('check' => array("test7", "test8"),
        'format' => '<iframe src="%s">'));

foreach ($test_array as &$el) {
  if (array_intersect($foobar, $el['check'])) {
    $foobar['foo_result'] = sprintf($el['format'], $foobar["foo_link"]);
    break;
}
```

`array_intersect` is likely to be the bottleneck, but only if your arrays are very large. If that's the case, I suggest you write a function `arrays_have_common_element` that does it more efficiently (you can turn one of the arrays into the keys of an associative array (the function `array_flip()` will do this for you), and then loop through the other array until it finds a match).

Comment: Oh wow [sprintf](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sprintf.php) looks awesome. Going to have read up on it. Thank you!

Comment: I will look at array_flip() and see how I go with that. I am not sure how to close a question but thank you for the quick response and the edit suggesting further improvements.

Comment: Questions only get closed if they're inappropriate, duplicates, etc. Otherwise you just accept the most suitable answer.